# preg_match matching multiple matches

Tags: preg-match

I'm trying to use preg_match to extract info from

```
href="domain.com/subdir/?key=value
```

The info I want are

1. domain.com
2. subdir
3. key
4. value

Can someone suggest what is the correct way to write the preg_match statement?

Thanks!

Comment: So your input is actually this snippet `href="domain.com/subdir/?key=value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this as your regex

/href="(.+..+?)/(.+?)/(\?.+?=.+)"/

that should work

```
preg_match('/href="(.+\..+?)\/(.+?)\/(\?.+?=.+)"/', $input, $matches);
echo "First Match: {$matches[0]}\n";
```

Comment: Is this how it should be written?

$test = "href='domain.com/subdir/?key=value'";
preg_match("/href='(.+\..+?)\/(.+?)\/(\?.+?=.+)'/", $test, $match);

echo $matches[0];
echo $matches[1];

Doesn't seem to work though.